# Generalization of Furstenberg's Multiple recurrence theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, number-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, ergodic-theory

Is there any generalization of Furstenberg's Multiple recurrence theorem for amenable semigroup, which is known? I did not find any result of this kind. So I guess it is not known yet. Please help me if you have any references in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I feel this question would also be appropriate for mathoverflow (be sure to mention that it's crossposted if you ask it over there).

Comment: @Surajit, you should ask on mathoverflow, but I would be incredible surprised if either (1) this has not been proven or (2) it is easily false. There are many people out there who extend results to amenable groups and probably semigroups as well.